# Ubuntu 16.04 Wi-Fi problem

Tags: wireless, 16.04, network-manager

I've been having this problem for almost a month now.

Every time I would reboot, wake-up, or even just boot my computer and log in, Network-Manager won't scan for Wi-Fi networks. It would just list under 'Wi-Fi Networks': "device not ready"
I have a physical switch on my laptop to toggle the wireless off or on and it's always on.

What I usually do to fix this problem is that I first turn off the wireless physical switch, then I type these commands,

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

after I do this, I use the physical switch and turn it back on.
After I do this it starts scanning.

This happens ever single time, and I always have to preform these steps to get running on the internet. My laptop didn't used to this, and I didn't do anything that would stand out and create this problem.

Is there a permanent fix to my problem?

Details about my card through ifconfig:

```
wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:d7:20:e3:64  
      inet addr:192.168.0.43  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::299a:d484:8c7:44c7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:83259 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:55870 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:94575910 (94.5 MB)  TX bytes:8886149 (8.8 MB)
```

Comment: did yo tried a good old "rfkill unblock all" in a terminal ?

Comment: What wifi card? Once you get it going, pull down the Network menu and check the Connection Info. What driver is it using? You can try adding the driver name to /etc/modules and see if that fixes your problem. In terminal, type **sudo gedit /etc/modules**. Then reboot. This will make the driver always load at boot time. Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overcame a similar problem once by writing a little script that reloads my network card driver module. It prints some driver info for you, and then restarts iwlwifi (probably your wireless driver, but if not you can change that line). It's crude, but has worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'network drivers:'
sudo lshw -C network

driver=$(sudo lshw -C network \
        | grep 'driver=' \
        | sed -e 's/^.*driver=//' \
        | cut -d' ' -f1)
echo 'apparent driver name: '$driver

echo 'restarting driver iwlwifi'
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: Would you have to execute this script ever single time? I want something that would just fix the problem and allow the network to just connect automatically like before.

Comment: Yes, it has to be run every time the problem happens. I saved the script to my path to make it easy to fire it off any time.